# Why is CakePHP 3 paginator not sending options to custom finder method?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to paginate with a custom finder in Cakephp 3.0.0-RC1. [The docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate) say that I should do this:

```
$customFinderOptions = [
    'tags' => $tags
];
$this->paginate = [
    'finder' => [
        'tagged' => $customFinderOptions
    ]
];
$articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);
```

So my controller method contains

```
$this->paginate = [
    'finder' => [
        'recentActivity' => [
            'limit' => 5,
            'offset' => 2,
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ]
    ]
];
$results = $this->paginate($this->ModelName);
```

At the top of `ModelNameTable::findRecentActivity()`, `pr($options)` results in this:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [whitelist] => Array
    (
        [0] => limit
        [1] => sort
        [2] => page
        [3] => direction
    )
)
```

**Where did `limit` and `offset` go?** Digging in the CakePHP 3 core a bit, I see at the top of ORM.Table.php

```
public function callFinder($type, Query $query, array $options = [])
{
    $query->applyOptions($options);
    $options = $query->getOptions();
    $finder = 'find' . $type;
    if (method_exists($this, $finder)) {
        return $this->{$finder}($query, $options);
    }
```

Ah, so `limit` and `offset` went into `$query`. Unfortunately, I can't think of a practical way to **get them back out from inside my custom finder method**.
I checked, and `$options` accurately reflects the options I set before it's overwritten by `$options = $query->getOptions();` and the `limit` and `offset` values are removed.

The docs led me to expect `$options` to be passed (in its entirety) to my custom finder method. So my question is...

1. **Am I using the paginator component / customer finder incorrectly?**
2. **Is this intended behavior, or something I should [report an issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/milestones/3.0.0) about?** I'm new to CakePHP 3 and still wrapping my head around it, so I didn't want to jump to the conclusion that it was a bug.

Sidenote: I know that I can hack around this by using different keys in `$options`, like `foo_limit` and `foo_offset` to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Those options you are passing are very likely going to contradict with the work the paginator does (which is actually setting offset and limit to the query). What do you expect to happen when the contradiction comes?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting `$limit` to be automatically and correctly applied to a paginated union, so I'm experimenting with applying it manually in various ways in the finder method. I didn't want to get into the specifics about my situation because I'm still playing around with different options, and if I can't find a proper solution I'll just make a separate question. But you're absolutely right that what I'm doing looks like an inadvisable meddling with the PaginatorComponent's well-engineered voodoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out...

1. It is **not true** that all options set for the custom finder are ignored. Most options that are listed in [José's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952071/52530) are **integrated into the query and then removed from `$options`** before `$options` is passed to the custom finder method.
2. However, **the custom finder's `limit` is always overwritten** by either `$this->paginate['limit']` or the default value of 20 (and likewise with `page`). But it looks like this has been identified as a bug and [is going to be fixed](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6047#issuecomment-78185617).

Comment: Thanks to José and Mark for helping me through this. It was driving me nuts for the past couple days.

Answer (score 1):

In understand where the confusion comes from. Apart from my concerns expressed in the question comments about the possibly contradictory options your query may get, I think you should know that the following list of options are directly copied to the query and not interpreted as custom options for your finder method:

- 'fields'
- 'conditions'
- 'join'
- 'order'
- 'limit'
- 'offset'
- 'group'
- 'having'
- 'contain'
- 'page'

Those options will call the matching query methods to set its internal state.

Comment: Awesome. Is there, however, any practical way to extract something like `limit` from the `$query` parameter that gets passed to the custom finder method? It appears to only be stored in `$query->_parts['limit']`, which is protected.

Comment: `$query->clause('limit')`

Comment: Oddly, `$query->clause('limit')` does **not** return the `limit` set in the options passed to the custom finder. It returns either the value for `Controller::paginate['limit']` or the default value of 20. It seems like `Controller::paginate['finder']['finderName']['limit']` is just being discarded. Which isn't hard to find a workaround for, but it seems odd.

Comment: It is not that odd, because of what I told you in the question comments. The job of the paginator is precisely setting the limit and offset for your query, I would be surprised if it didn't change them.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what I'm getting at. The value for `limit` set in `$this->paginate` as a finder option is **completely ignored** instead of being integrated into the query. If it's CakePHP's intention that "the following list of options are directly copied to the query ... for your finder method", then it appears to me to be a bug.